# Watermarking image position[asp.net]

Tags: asp.net, image, position, watermark

I'm trying to follow this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2927/Creating-a-Watermarked-Photograph-with-GDI-for-NET) and it was easy to implement **`text over image`** and now my problem is in the above mentioned article the image watermark was placed **10 pixels from left** so how do I place image similarly to **top right,top middle,middle left, center,middle right and similary to bottom**.

Here is how it was placed to the top right corner :

```
int xPosOfWm = ((phWidth - wmWidth)-10);
int yPosOfWm = 10;

grWatermark.DrawImage(
  imgWatermark,
  new Rectangle(
    xPosOfWm, yPosOfWm,
    wmWidth, wmHeight
  ),
  0, 0,
  wmWidth, wmHeight,
  GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
  imageAttributes
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you will have to calculate your image height and width first

calculate the original Image height and width

```
Image oImage="path";
var oheight=oImage.Height;
var oWidth=oImage.width;
```

Now Calculate the Image which you want to place over it

```
var WmImage="path";
var wWheight=WmImage.Height;
var wWidth=WmoImage.width;
```

top-right

```
var left=oWidth-wWidth-10;
var top=oheight-10;
//draw the wate mark image on thse point
oImage.DrawImage(imgWatermark,new Rectangle(left,top,wmWidth,
wmHeight),0,0,wmWidth,wmHeight,GraphicsUnit.Pixel,imageAttributes);
```

similarly you can calculate for other images alos.

Answer (score 0):

The current code doesn't place the watermark at the top left, it places at the top right.

To place it at the top left, you use:

```
int xPosOfWm = 10;
int yPosOfWm = 10;
```

To position the watermark horisontally at the left, center and right:

```
int xPosOfWm = 10;

int xPosOfWm = (phWidth - wmWidth) / 2;

int xPosOfWm = (phWidth - wmWidth) - 10;
```

To position the watermark vertically at the top, middle and bottom:

```
int yPosOfWm = 10;

int yPosOfWm = (phHeight - wmHeight) / 2;

int yPosOfWm = (phHeight - wmHeight) - 10;
```

Just combine one horisontal with one vertical to get any combination that you want.