# How do I solve my watermark position issue?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing an image watermarking application using C# Windows Form in Visual Studio 2017. Most of my codes are referenced from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-a-simple-watermarking-utility-in-C-Sharp/, which helped me a lot. However I find the codes provided for watermark position is too limited hence I added a new set of codes to enable more position choices for the watermark. (Top Left, Top Right, Bottom Left, Bottom Right etc)

However, there's some issues with the codes I use for my 'top' watermark position. According to this link ([Watermarking image position[asp.net]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794290/watermarking-image-positionasp-net)) and this link (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31538/%2FArticles%2F31538%2FWatermarker-Embedding-image-and-text-watermarks) I found that the code for 'Top Left' position is a single integer value for both X and Y values.

The issue is that my watermark position is not really at the 'top' of the image (even though I used the codes from the above links I've found). Also, I realized that the bigger the text size of the watermark text I set, the lower the position of the watermark would be. How can I resolve this issue? 
I would not want the user to select an option for 'Top Left' and sees the resulting watermark position that is nearly at the center of the image because the text size is large.

The code I'm using for 'Top Left':

```
if (rbHorl.Checked == true && rbVerl.Checked == true)
        {
            X = (int)10;
            Y = (int)10;
        }
// X (represents Left) and Y represents (Top)
```

[image: Watermark image 1]
In this image, the size of the watermark text I've set to is 8. The position is not really at the top. I expect to see it at the extreme top corner of the image. The watermark position works just as fine for my 'Bottom' position.

The codes I use for 'Bottom Left':

```
else if (rbHorl.Checked == true && rbVerr.Checked == true)
        {
            X = (int)10;
            Y = (int)(pictureBox.Image.Height - sz.Height) - 10;
        }
//rbHorl represents Left and rbVerr represents Top
```

I've switched between my X and Y values, so my X is the y-axis and vice versa.

[image: Watermark Image 2]
In this image, I've set the size of my watermark text to be 72. The position of the watermark is even lower than size 8. It does not stay at the top left corner of the image as what I expected.

As you can see the textbox also increases in size as the size of the watermark text increases. I would appreciate if I can also get help on how I can keep the size of the textbox fixed while increasing the size of the text. The font and size of the watermark text is set using the fontDialog which is already in-built with Visual Studios.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Is rbVerl supposed to mean Top?  Don't set the font of the TextBox if you don't want the TextBox to resize.  Just store the font information in a variable.  It doesn't look like the image is covering the entire PictureBox — that makes it hard to position it correctly.

Comment: Looks like you need to determine how the anchor point of an image is handled (i.e. does it position the image centered on the coordinate versus positioning at the top left of the image) and then compensate accordingly using the resolution of the image. You should also resize the image based on the size of the frame (e.g. if the watermark image is a big 4K image and the frame is only 720p, you gotta downscale it considerably!), and handle any padding (i.e. not putting the image on the exact edge of the frame).

Comment: Where's the code that performs the painting of the text? With this: `Y = (int)10;` as a hint, IMO it's hard to provide any meaningful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with numbers and managed to put my watermark position at the 'Top Left' with the following codes:

```
if (rbHorl.Checked == true && rbVerl.Checked == true)//VTop Left
        {
            X = (int)10;
            Y = (int)-30;
        }
```

I also realized that I have confused myself with the labeling of my buttons and hence the wrong codes used for the positions for Top Left, Centre and Right.

As for not enlarging the text in the texbox as I increase the size of the watermark text, I removed the following line of code from my existing codes (commented out):

```
private void btnSetfont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //defailt the current font and color to that 
        //used in the watermark textbox
        fontDialog1.ShowColor = true;
        //fontDialog1.Font = tbWatermarktext.Font;
        fontDialog1.Color = tbWatermarktext.ForeColor;

if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            myFont = fontDialog1.Font;
            myWatermarkColor = fontDialog1.Color;
            //tbWatermarktext.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
            tbWatermarktext.ForeColor = fontDialog1.Color;
        }
    }
```

Despite having solved the above two issues, I still have the problem where the position of the watermark would go lower if the size of the watermark text is set to too big. In this image, a watermark text size of 72 would make the intended 'Top Left' position of the watermark to look like the Centre Left position:

[image]